# Extract and populate id3 tag information from filename

Tags: macos, tags, mp3, id3

Does anyone know an application for mac or an applescript (like the ones at dougscripts) that can be used to populate id3 tag information for an mp3 track via information in the filenames?

I have a bunch of files that are formatted as

```
[album] - [track number] - [artist] - [track title].mp3
```

but all the actual id3 tags are empty (except for track title which is just a copy of the filename).  I'd write the script myself but have no previous experience working with applescripts and was hoping that maybe someone had run across something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's this application that I found called TriTag that does EXACTLY what I wanted to do.  Hopefully this helps someone else out looking for a similar solution